# Soundcloud iframe embed is throwing a type error / undefined exception

Tags: soundcloud

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeItem' of undefined",
>   source: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/assets/widget-9f6de367.js (61)

I'm getting this when trying to use the soundcloud iframe embed in an Android WebView. This was working a month or so ago but it seems that potentially the internal embed code has been changed and now causes this issue.

**Update**

Seems like it had to do with the widget trying to interface with local storage, where Android's WebView has dom storage disabled by default, turning it on fixed the issue.

Still, SoundCloud should probably guard against this it seems, probably something that wasn't expected to happen, but breaks the widget entirely for embedded webviews within Android by default, and definitely didn't a few weeks / month or so ago.

Comment: This is a soundcloud embedded error for all platforms.

Comment: Well sure, maybe so, but that doesn't explain anything. Obviously it's an error thrown by the widget, but need to know why.

Comment: It's an error with the soundcloud SDK due to `LocalStorage` issues. Virtually impossible to fix until Soundcloud decide to do so.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo there we go thanks, that definitely is the issue. Android's webview has local storage / dom storage disabled by default, enabling it fixes this. Definitely something they broke recently. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

The very sequence for the upload function is confusing it will say the track item or material sample or song you are uploading is saved or uploaded then it would say that it is processing the upload then a pop up message will appear and then it will say click save to finish your upload and then you will save and nothing will happen like the link or the button it's self has a malfunction or it has gone inactive what's up with that?